# How to Get a Secret User in keycloak

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have an application using spring boot, angular and keycloak in version 18.0. In the application all the users has 2FA configured by keycloak. I need recover the MFA secret of all the users. Is there any easy way to retrieve this secret?

Note: I need the secret of the users and not the client secret

Comment: Why are you trying to get user secret key? Seems ethically questionable.

Comment: I need the secret because I need to do OTP code validation on critical system screens. The secret would be used to generate the OTP code in the backend and then compare it